# go from unsafe password for secure password

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, password-encryption

I'm new in the asp.net and I want to hear about who knows something about making passwords secure.

Here's how I'm currently doing it but I'm wondering if there's a more secure way?

```
protected void ButtonOpdaterPassword_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string id = Session["id"].ToString();

    string password = TextBoxPassword.Text;


    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString());
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = conn;


    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE users SET password = @password WHERE Id = @id;";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", id);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);


    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();

    Response.Redirect("/admin-panel-2/Default.aspx");
}
```

Comment: You need proper hashing and salting of passwords. If you don't know how to do this properly, you should be using an API that already does this properly, like the ASP.Net membership APIs

Comment: This may be subject to opinion, but I'd suggest looking into `PBKDF2` for salting passwords.

Comment: @DrewKennedy There is no reason they should need to do that themselves in ASP.NET. It has a very well described membership provider system that allows for a developer to depend on much safer much better audited libraries than they themselves could write.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following library: http://efxa.org/2014/02/28/the-project-hasher-decent-implementation-of-salted-hashing/

It is a personal implementation and is open source.

Comment: Thanks for link, i try its here now, :) just have trouble getting it to work 100%, as it will not cooperate with me right now

https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm#aspsourcecode

Comment: My implementation is better than this. It includes many other characteristics. I was inspired by this one and many other to do it.

Comment: I can not just see the idea behind it to set it up, I'm brand new to asp.net when I just come over from php,.